# Why does my trait need a lifetime parameter?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Being a Rust newbie, I probably somewhat naively started with this:

```
...

pub trait Decode<T> {
    fn decode_from<R: io::Read + ?Sized>(&mut self, stream: &mut R) -> T;
}

pub struct MQTTFrame<'a> {
    pub payload: &'a Vec<u8>,
}

pub struct MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> {
    pub payload: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a> Decode<MQTTFrame<'a>> for MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> {
    fn decode_from<R: io::Read + ?Sized>(&mut self, stream: &mut R) ->    MQTTFrame<'a> {
        stream.read(&mut self.payload);
        MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }
    }
}
```

Which, when trying to compile, was greeted with:

```
src/testbed/mod.rs:31:24: 31:36 error: cannot infer an appropriate   lifetime for automatic coercion due to conflicting requirements [E0495]
src/testbed/mod.rs:31         MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src/testbed/mod.rs:29:5: 32:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime  parameter as shown: fn decode_from<R: io::Read + ?Sized>(&'a mut self,   stream: &mut R)
 -> MQTTFrame<'a>
src/testbed/mod.rs:29     fn decode_from<R: io::Read + ?Sized>(&mut self, stream: &mut R) -> MQTTFrame<'a> {
src/testbed/mod.rs:30         stream.read(&mut self.payload);
src/testbed/mod.rs:31         MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }
src/testbed/mod.rs:32     }
```

Somewhere on StackOverflow - sorry, I forgot where - someone in a similar case suggested to add a lifetime parameter like so (omitting unchanged code):

```
pub trait Decode<'a, T> {
    fn decode_from<R: io::Read + ?Sized>(&'a mut self, stream: &mut R) -> T;
}

impl<'a> Decode<'a, MQTTFrame<'a>> for MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> {
    fn decode_from<R: io::Read + ?Sized>(&'a mut self, stream: &mut R) -> MQTTFrame<'a> {
        stream.read(&mut self.payload);
        MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }
    }
}
```

And lo and behold! It compiles. Now if I could only understand *why* it compiles. Could someone explain

1. why the original code did not compile?
2. why the modified code compiles?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a reduced testcase that fails to compile ([playpen](http://is.gd/EQaNvB)):

```
pub trait Decode<T> {
    fn decode_from<'b>(&'b mut self) -> T;
}

pub struct MQTTFrame<'a> {
    pub payload: &'a Vec<u8>,
}

pub struct MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> {
    pub payload: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a> Decode<MQTTFrame<'a>> for MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> {
    fn decode_from<'b>(&'b mut self) -> MQTTFrame<'a> {
        MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }
    }
}
```

Note that I have [elided the lifetimes](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html#lifetime-elision) for the `decode_from` function and removed the redundant stream parameter.

It is clear then that the function is taking a reference with an arbitrarily short lifetime `'b`, and then extending it to have lifetime `'a`. This is a problem with mutable references as then you can borrow something mutably and immutably at the same time:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![];
    /* lifetime 'a */ {
        let mut decoder = MQTTFrameDecoder{ payload: &mut v };
        let frame: MQTTFrame;
        /* lifetime 'b */ {
            frame = decoder.decode_from(); // borrows decoder just for lifetime 'b
        }
        // v is mutably borrowed (by decoder) and immutably borrowed (by frame) at the same time! oops!
        decoder.payload.push(1);
        println!("{:?}", frame.payload);
    }
}
```

For this reason the borrow checker refuses to let the function compile.

If you force the reference to `decoder` to have lifetime `'a`, though, then there is no longer a problem. The compiler cannot use the reference with the shorter lifetime, it must mutably borrow `decoder` for longer, and so the compiler should give us an error when we try to borrow it again.

In order to achieve this, we would like to write

```
fn decode_from(&'a mut self) -> MQTTFrame<'a> {
    MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }
}
```

But now we get an error:

```
<anon>:14:5: 16:6 error: method `decode_from` has an incompatible type for trait:
 expected bound lifetime parameter 'b,
    found concrete lifetime [E0053]
```

To fix this, we need to have our trait be aware that you can only `decode_from` certain lifetimes, not arbitrary ones. So change decode to

```
pub trait Decode<'a, T> {
    fn decode_from(&'a mut self) -> T;
}
```

And make the appropriate change to the implementation

```
impl<'a> Decode<'a, MQTTFrame<'a>> for MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> { ... }
```

Now if we try the code above (playpen is.gd/BLStYq), the borrow checker complains:

```
<anon>:28:9: 28:24 error: cannot borrow `*decoder.payload` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]
<anon>:28         decoder.payload.push(1);
```

That's because, now, the reference to `decoder` must have lifetime `'a` when it is taken in order to call the function `decode_from`. Comment out the offending line and the rest of the example compiles! This code is now safe because no mutable lifetimes are being extended.

---

Aside:

As the reference to `decoder` must live as long as the decoder itself, you can't actually use `decoder` at all after you have called `decode_from`. As this is the case, it may be better to express this by taking `self` instead of `&'a mut self`. Then the syntax is a little cleaner, and it is obvious that once a decoder has been used then it can't be used again.

```
pub trait Decode<T> {
    fn decode_from(self) -> T;
}

pub struct MQTTFrame<'a> {
    pub payload: &'a Vec<u8>,
}

pub struct MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> {
    pub payload: &'a mut Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a> Decode<MQTTFrame<'a>> for MQTTFrameDecoder<'a> {
    fn decode_from(self) -> MQTTFrame<'a> {
        MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Djzin, this answer has the ring of truth, although I do not fully understand it. I will need some time to think about it. Don't be surprised if I get back to you with more questions. One I already have: if the Rust community says "mutable reference" does it really mean "(immutable) reference to a mutable value"?

Comment: I accepted your answer because I believe I now almost fully understand your reasoning:

Comment: I accepted your answer because I believe I now almost fully understand your reasoning: a reference to `MQTTFrameDecoder` is - by transitivity - a *mutable* reference to the vector `payload`. Likewise, a reference to `MQTTFrame` is a reference to the same vector `payload`. The code you presented would lead - through scope widening - to a situation where a mutable and a distinct immutable reference - `decoder` and `frame` - were in scope. Which is forbidden. Correct?

Comment: I wonder what rule the compiler employs to reach this conclusion. I doubt that it uses some kind of speculative data flow analysis to essentially do what you did, namely construct a counter example. In the original test case you presented, when the compiler sees `MQTTFrame{ payload: self.payload }` there is lifetime `'b` assigned to `self.payload` and lifetime `'a` assigned to the `MQTTFrame` about to be constructed - and hence to that frame's `payload`. And probably that is what the compiler complains about: that lifetime needs to be uniquely determined. Correct?

Comment: "A reference to `MQTTFrameDecoder` is - by transitivity - a mutable reference to the vector `payload`" - this is correct. However, it is not correct that the compiler needs the lifetime to be "uniquely determined". It just needs *some* lifetime to work. The static rules in place see a type with lifetime `'b` (arbitrarily short) trying to coerce into a type with lifetime `'a`. If `'b : 'a` (b lives at least as long as a) or `'b = 'a` then there is no problem. Compare the examples [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=84758e66a70d87b02aa5&version=stable).

Comment: "If the Rust community says "mutable reference" does it really mean "(immutable) reference to a mutable value"" - yes exactly. "Mutable reference to t" is declared `let x = &mut t;` and if the type of `t` is `T`, `x` has type `&'a mut T`. A reference that can be mutated depends on the *binding* and is declared `let mut x = &t`. `x` here has type `&'a T`, so it is not a "mutable reference", even though it is a reference that is mutable.

Comment: Great clarification of the static lifetime rule enforced by the compiler here, much appreciated. It's beginning to make sense to me.

Comment: I strongly suspected that "mutable reference" had this meaning in Rust. That sums things up nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lifetime elision works only in very simple cases. This makes them weak, but easy to explain (also simple cases are surprisingly common).

As soon as you have a generic lifetime parameter, elision no longer applies – the compiler refuses to guess your intention.